# JSESSIONID changed in IE11

Tags: spring-mvc, session, servlets, internet-explorer-11, session-cookies

In my Spring MVC application, every http request generate new JSESSIONID in IE11, but in other browsers keep same session id until user logout.

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpSession httpSession = attr.getRequest().getSession();
    System.out.println("Session ID :: "+httpSession.getId());
```

How can i keep same session id after user login in IE11. i'm not able to get current user from session due to Session id change. How can i solve this problem in IE11.

Comment: The most likely cause is that your IE11 is configured to reject all cookies. If the browser is disallowed from storing session cookies (completely or for a specific site) your application won't get that back with subsequent request.

Comment: i allowed all first and third part cookies, but still i'm getting the same

Comment: Did you enabe “Always allow session cookies”? Did you try in some other PC?

Comment: yes, i enabled “Always allow session cookies” in different machine also, but no luck